# Ajax control toolkit asssembly reference error

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I am trying to install the ajax controll toolkit in an asp.net project.I have used Nugget to download the library into the project and loaded each control into the toolbox but when I try to use any of the controls I get this error:

```
Error   3   The type 'System.Web.UI.Design.ExtenderControlDesigner' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.   D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\C# Book\ASP.NET\WebSite12\Default.aspx    14
```

After reading this error I added this in the configuration file:

```
<assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</assemblies>
```

I understand that this should point to the assembly I need but it does not work and also maybe someone can tell me from where should I have goten this string in the first place I have seen similar strings used for providersi in asp.net at the type property and I cant understand from where should I get them especialy the PublicKeyToken.

This is my entire code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:AlwaysVisibleControlDesigner ID="AlwaysVisible" runat="server">

        </asp:AlwaysVisibleControlDesigner>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the contents of the web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" >
          <assemblies>
              <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          </assemblies>
      </compilation>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also a second configuration file has been added after installing the ajax control toolkit via nugget called packages.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AjaxControlToolkit" version="4.1.60919" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

What am I doing wrong here?Why am I getting that error?

**EDIT**

It turns out I had to add an aditional assembly for this to work:

```
 <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
          <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
 </assemblies>
```

Now I am getting an error that says:

```
**Error 2   Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AlwaysVisibleControlDesigner' does not have a public property named 'TargetControlID'. D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\C# Book\ASP.NET\WebSite12\Default.aspx    14
```

**

This is the code:

```
<asp:AlwaysVisibleControlDesigner ID="AlwaysVisible"  runat="server" TargetControlID="Panel1" HorizontalOffset="10" HorizontalSide="Right" VerticalOffset="10" >
 </asp:AlwaysVisibleControlDesigner>
```

I am prety sure that this should be corect I got this example from the book Proffesional asp.net in C# and VB

Somehow my code is not getting the ajaxcontrol toolkit properties.How can I corect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem a long time ago.
The problem with my code was that it used two different versions of Ajax control toolkit.
The Toolbox had the latest Ajax control toolkit(the one With color picker, editor control) and the reference added in the project was of a older version.

How to solve:

1. Remove the Ajax Control tab from the toolbox.
2. Re-add the tab and right-click on the tab, Select Choose Items and browse to the
   `AjaxControltoolkit.dll` file in your own project and press OK(Just
   to make sure that we are using the same version in both the places)
3. Clean and rebuild the solution and you are ready to go.