# asp.net4.5 AjaxControlToolkit error version in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, webforms

I was trying to use AjaxFileupload but couldn't because "may be missing some components" Ajax Toolkit components "Ajax Control Toolkit .NET 4.5" http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091. After installation? I did my upload with ajax easily but know i'm facing this issue sometime :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The requested script resource 'Compat.Timer.Timer.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the application references version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The requested script resource 'Compat.Timer.Timer.js' requires version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' of the ASP.NET AJAX Framework. To use this resource, make sure that the application references version 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'.

Project became unstable. I try to remove and reinstall ([Ajax control toolkit asssembly reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439213/ajax-control-toolkit-asssembly-reference-error)) but without success ( 
I deleted all file in project and download 2 day earlier version from server but it didn't help !!! are there anything i have to do?? I can move more because i'm using a lot of Ajax in this project !!!

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Defaut.aspx.cs" Inherits="Group" %>

    <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
```

in body: call scripttool

```
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="True"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

In Config something like this:

```
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Can Someone help ?

**edit:** It's like that this error is more often with Chrome and Safari. (At the moment Fierox and IE seems to work)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your bin folder or the folder your dlls are in, and check the version of AjaxControlToolkit that you have in there. See if it is the same as the error (Version= 4.5.7.1213). If it is, then check your web config file, you may have two references in there to the tool kit. I would start in the bin folder.

Comment: I just checked it. but there in my bin folder there is only one file AjaxControlToolkit (Version= 4.5.7.1213). In my web config only one reference ` <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" /> `. thank you. Another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add these 2 lines in ***web.config***:

**1. Under `<SafeControls>`:**

```
<SafeControl Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="True" />
```

**2. Under `<assemblies>`:**

```
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" />
```

In `<assemblies>` public key token needs to be mentioned.

---

In ***design / master page***:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

(Note: Here tag prefix chosen is `ajaxToolkit`, so will refer ajaxcontrols with it)

Replace the `asp:scriptmanager` with `AjaxControlToolkitScriptManager` (if does not exist then insert):

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true"/>
```

---

*Now **AjaxControls** can be used on design page under these tags:*

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>    
       ---your code---    
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```